# Tkinter Focus not working - Need button keypad to type into 2 different entries based on focus

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, raspberry-pi, focus

Please Help!  I'm at my wits end over here... I am new to learning Python and tkinter and I have not found anyone trying to do what I am, so I keep trying different people's answers and nothing is working.  I can't understand the docs, and every tutorial I find is not quite exactly what I need to do, so I end up with irrelevant code bits that just lead to more problems.

I want to build a GUI for a touchscreen program for a Raspberry Pi that will allow me to program a relay to turn on for "x" seconds, then turn off for "y" seconds, then repeat forever until I stop it.  The touchscreen needs to have large buttons for each of the numbers 0 - 9, a button to clear the values, buttons to confirm each value once it has been input in the entry box, a button to start the cycle, and a button to exit.  There also needs to be 2 entry boxes, one for "On", and one for "Off", so that the user can see the numbers they have entered for each value. This is what is messing me up. I can get it to work for one entry box, but not two.

Please someone tell me what is wrong.  I don't know how to tell each button to place its value only in the entry field that has focus.  I can only figure out how to tell it to input in one entry or the other, regardless of which has focus.

I also need the numbers to appear in the entry boxes in the correct sequence, so that when you type a "3" and then a "0", the program reads "30". Right now it is producing "03".

Here's the code.  I have some things commented out currently, and yes, I know it's ugly:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    try:
        # for Python 2
        from Tkinter import *
    except ImportError:
        # for Python 3
        from tkinter import *

    import ttk as ttk
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import time
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.LOW)

    running = True


    def water():
        go.grid(column=4, row=3, rowspan=6, columnspan=6, sticky=W)

    def go():
        running = True    
        x = on.get()
        y = off.get()
        y = float(y)
        x = float(x)        
        if running:
            GPIO.output(4, False)
            print("Off")
            time.sleep(y)
            GPIO.output(4, True)
            print("On")
            time.sleep(x)    
            root.after(10, go)    

    def clear():
        on.set('')
        off.set('')
        global running
        running = False
        go.grid_forget()
        on_entry.focus()

    def select(value):
        if on_entry.focus():
            on_entry.set(value)
        elif off_entry.focus():
            off_entry.set(value)

    def geton():
        on_entry.get()
        off_entry.focus()

    def getoff():
        off_entry.get()
        water()

    #this is the PROBLEM!!!!
    def set_text(text):
        on_entry.insert(0,text)


    #buttons = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']    
    #varRow = 5
    #varColumn = 0

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("740x480+0+0")
    root.title("Waterboy")

    #need to make this fullscreen
    mainframe = Frame(root)
    mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
    mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    go = Button(mainframe, text="GO", command=go, bg="green", width=6, height=11)

    #seconds on and off
    on = StringVar()
    off = StringVar()

    on_entry = Entry(mainframe, width=8, textvariable=on)
    on_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
    off_entry = Entry(mainframe, width=8, textvariable=off)
    off_entry.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))


    on_entry.focus_set()

    onok = Button(mainframe, text="OK", command=geton, bg="white", width=6, height=1)
    onok.grid(column=4, row=1, sticky=W)

    offok = Button(mainframe, text="OK", command=getoff, bg="white", width=6, height=1)
    offok.grid(column=4, row=2, sticky=W)

    reset = Button(mainframe, text="Reset Values", command=clear, bg='yellow', width=16, height=2)
    reset.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky=W)

    adios = Button(mainframe, text="EXIT", command=exit, bg="red", width=16, height=2)
    adios.grid(column=2, row=7, sticky=W)

    secon = ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Input # Seconds Water ON and press 'OK' -->", width=36)
    secon.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2)
    secoff = ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Input # Seconds Water OFF and press 'OK' -->", width=36)
    secoff.grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=2)

    one = Button(mainframe, text="1", width=16, height=2, command=lambda:set_text("1")
    one.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=W)
    two = Button(mainframe, text="2", width=16, height=2, command=lambda:set_text("2")
    two.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=W)
    three = Button(mainframe, text="3", width=16, height=2, command=lambda:set_text("3")
    three.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=W)
    four = Button(mainframe, text="4", width=16, height=2, command=lambda:set_text("4")
    four.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=W)
    five = Button(mainframe, text="5", width=16, height=2, command=lambda:set_text("5")
    five.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=W)
    six = Button(mainframe, text="6", width=16, height=2, command=lambda:set_text("6")
    six.grid(column=2, row=5, sticky=W)
    seven = Button(mainframe, text="7", width=16, height=2, command=lambda:set_text("7")
    seven.grid(column=0, row=6, sticky=W)
    eight = Button(mainframe, text="8", width=16, height=2, command=lambda:set_text("8")
    eight.grid(column=1, row=6, sticky=W)
    nine = Button(mainframe, text="9", width=16, height=2, command=lambda:set_text("9")
    nine.grid(column=2, row=6, sticky=W)
    zero = Button(mainframe, text="0", width=16, height=2, command=lambda:set_text("0")
    zero.grid(column=1, row=7, sticky=W)


    #for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=4, pady=4)


    #root.bind('<Return>', go)

    #for button in buttons:
    #    command = lambda x=button: select(x)
    #    Button(mainframe, text=button, width=5, bg="white", command = command).grid(row = varRow, column=varColumn)
    #    varColumn += 1
    #    if varColumn > 2 and varRow == 4:
    #        varColumn = 0
    #        varRow += 1
    #    if varColumn > 2 and varRow == 5:
    #        varColumn = 0
    #        varRow += 1
    #    if varColumn > 2 and varRow == 6:
    #        varColumn = 0
    #        varRow += 1

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `focus_get` on the root window to get the widget that has focus. You can then insert text using that widget. You can specify the special index of "end" to have the text inserted at the end of the widget.

For example:

```
def set_text(text)
    widget = root.focus_get()
    widget.insert("end", text)
```

Of course, you'll want to do some validation to make sure that the widget is a text or entry widget.

Also, be careful with using ttk -- the default behavior of ttk button widgets is to steal the keyboard focus.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this didn't really help though.  I've since done away with the number buttons in favor of sliding scales, which do the job and avoid the entry boxes altogether.  Now my problem is making an exit button that the program will look for even while in a loop.  I'll post a new question with that soon.